# How to write 3 separate formula in one equation?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

[image]

I want to write all these above 3 formula in one horizontal line,
how can i do that?

```
\begin{equation}
y= {w}^{T}x  where

{x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}}

and 
{
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}
}


.
\end{equation}
where  
\begin{equation*}
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

But it give me this output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think that our code does not only split things in several lines but also gives you error messages for the empty lines. One quick fix is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y= {w}^{T}x\quad\text{where }
w = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1} \\
w_{2} \\
\vdots \\
w_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I used `\text` where appropriate, got rid of the empty lines and also assumed that you do not want to specify `x` twice. In a full document you probably want to add punctuation.

Comment: Thank a lot! It works well

Answer (score 1):

Use only one `equation`-environment:

```
\begin{equation}
y= {w}^{T}x  \text{ where }
{x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}}
\text{ and }
{
w = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{1} \\
w_{2} \\
\vdots \\
w_{m} 
\end{bmatrix}
}
.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Also note using `\text{...}` when putting some text into math mode instead of writing the words naked because then, they're handled as variables (what you can see at the italic font which doesn't look right).

Comment: The braces grouping the math segments containing the matrices aren't needed,  Otherwise good.

Comment: Yes, they aren't needed but were given in the original code. They may have been set for structure purposes.